# fstab won't mount during boot but does during runtime

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

I want to mount my windows shared NTFS partition immediatly on boot but this fails during boot and works when I mount the drive later during runtime.

It does mount on boot when I set the location to /mnt/[device name].

my fstab line:

```
/dev/sda10 /home/tycho/Documents/fontys ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,auto,umask=077,fmask=177 0 0
```

What causes this?

Comment: Did you try mounting by UUID? I had better luck with that than by device name.  I wondered if it was a race condition between assignments of the device designators and the mount.  To do this, replace /dev/sda10 with UUID=[UUID of the partition]

Comment: I've tried it before but I'll try again for the sake of being sure that that is not the issue

Comment: Changing the device to the UUID did not work. I still have the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have any windows shares, so I can't look at what I had, that worked.  I just remembered that I used UUIDs.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the line you've shown:

- The `noauto` option tells the computer to *not* automatically mount the volume. This is most likely the source of your problem.
- Your options are broken up into two groups; you've got `uid=1000,gid=1000,noauto,x-` and then `gvfs-show,umask=077,fmask=177`, with several spaces between those two groups. I'm not that familiar with NTFS-3g options, but I suspect it should be `x-gvfs-show` in the middle, not `x-` by itself (which would be a very strange option name) and `gvfs-show`. This issue could be a typo you accidentally inserted when cutting-and-pasting the line. If not, the options in the second group are likely to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not solve my problem.
I realise I should've re-edited the command (I changed to no auto to prevent the error from happening) and x-gvfs-show is irrelevent to the error I am having. It adds the drive to my file manager interface.

the spaces are accidental when creating this question...

Comment: @TychoHertogs: if you're receiving errors, please share them with us :)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini  I'm getting no actual error log (maybe it is written somewhere) but it only tells me failed to mount /home/tycho/Documents/fontys press s to continue or m for manual recovery

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? If it's Windows 8 or later, you ***must*** disable both the Fast Startup and Hibernate features in Windows, since those features wreak havoc with shared filesystems in a multi-boot environment.

Comment: @RodSmith I am using windows 10, I have disabled both of those options already. The drive is an extra partion and doesn't contain windows. I also can already mount the partition but it seems it doesn't have access/rights to the location, since it does mount in i.e. /mnt/[drivename]